# Would this Vivitar 75-205mm 1:3.8 macro lens fit on Nikon D610 dslr?

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, vivitar

would the lens pictured (Vivitar 75-205mm 1:3.8 macro focusing lens) fit on a Nikon D610 dslr? thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The photo is a little fuzzy, so I am not positive, but that looks to be a Pentax K mount. It will not fit without the help of an adapter like [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/995090-REG/fotodiox_pk_nk_g_pro_nikon_f_mount_lens.html).